# Are there JavaScript or Ruby versions of "HTML tidy"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, tidy

Does there exist a library similar to HTML tidy (http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) that is not OS specific (needs to be compiled on each host). Basically i just want to validate/clean the HTML sent to me by the user.

```
<p>hello</p></p><br>
```

should become

```
<p>hello</p>
<br/>
```

Something in javascript or ruby would work for me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby you can parse the HTML in Nokogiri, which will let you check for errors, then have it output the HTML, which will clean up missing closing tags and such. Notice in the following HTML that the title and p tags are not closed correctly, but Nokogiri adds the ending tags.

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = '<html><head><title>the title</head><body><p>a paragraph</body></html>'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
puts "Errors found" if (doc.errors.any?)
puts doc.to_html
# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html>
# >> <head>
# >> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
# >> <title>the title</title>
# >> </head>
# >> <body><p>a paragraph</p></body>
# >> </html>
```

Alternately you can open a connection to `/usr/bin/tidy` and tell it to do the dirty work:

```
require 'open3'

html = '<html><head><title>the title</head><body><p>a paragraph</body></html>'

stdin, stdout, stderr = Open3.popen3('/usr/bin/tidy -qi')
stdin.puts html
stdin.close
puts stdout.read
# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
# >> 
# >> <html>
# >> <head>
# >>   <meta name="generator" content=
# >>   "HTML Tidy for Mac OS X (vers 31 October 2006 - Apple Inc. build 15.3.6), see www.w3.org">
# >> 
# >>   <title>the title</title>
# >> </head>
# >> 
# >> <body>
# >>   <p>a paragraph</p>
# >> </body>
# >> </html>
```

Comment: [Loofah](http://loofah.rubyforge.org/loofah/) is another gem built on Nokogiri which does sanitizing.

Comment: sanitize gem (https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize) uses nokogiri and works (thanks!). Does anyone know something that could work on the client side to provide them instant feedback.

Comment: What are you envisioning when you say "instant feedback"? An instant update in their browser? That'd be an AJAX call to update the contents of a `<div>` block.

Comment: true but that would include saving the input back to the server and then rendering it again (not possible for an update on every key stroke for example). If there are really no javascript sanitizers i'll implement something in AJAX. Thanks

Comment: Found something!
http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/browse/trunk/closure/goog/format/htmlprettyprinter.js?r=222

Answer (score 1):

Had you checked this before? http://tidy.rubyforge.org/

Comment: yes but the problem is with: Tidy.path = '/usr/lib/tidylib.so' which needs to be compiled for the host

Answer (score 1):

html-tidy has been compiled to javascript (using emscripten).

See [the demo](http://lovasoa.github.io/tidy-html5/demo.html) and download [tidy.js](http://lovasoa.github.io/tidy-html5/tidy.js).

If you are brave enough, you can compile it to javascript yourself, with the options you want. See https://github.com/lovasoa/tidy-html5

Answer (score 0):

There is a java port [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) but no other ports that I know of, there may be some way you call HTML tidy from Ruby that works for you, prahaps call the html tidy app on the command line from your ruby webapp.

Comment: Yes I know this! i am just mentioning that it is the only port I know of.

Comment: unfortunately i can't install java on my host (or else that could work), but thanks

Answer (score 0):

Would the [W3 Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) work for you?

Or are you wanting something to fix the errors?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a beautifier use Pretty Diff.

http://prettydiff.com/?m=beautify&html