# Sanitizing html with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I need to validate an html string , more specifically I'm trying to check it is a valid xml tree(all open tags are closed etc).

```
Nokogiri::XML('<div>' + html + '</div>') { |config| config.strict }
```

This raises an exception if the html string is invalid , which is what I want.
However, I have an issue with self-closing tags such as

```
<br> or <img>
```

These will cause the code above to raise an exception since they don't have the completing closing tags.It's indeed invalid XML so Nokogiri is doing it's job. However , for my needs , it SHOULD be permitted . I want the same behavior of config.strict but allow br and img tags . 
Any thoughts?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240107/are-there-javascript-or-ruby-versions-of-html-tidy

Comment: Why are you using an XML parser to work with HTML? What do you plan to do about the automatic closing rules for `<p>` and such? For example, `<p>Where is<p>pancakes house?` is perfectly valid HTML (check http://validator.w3.org/ if you don't believe me) but you're not going to get that through an XML parser.

Comment: @muistooshort I didn't find a similar Nokogiri method for html . your example can't happen under my requirements ...

Comment: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri#HTML-class_method

Comment: @matt I see what you're saying , however  Nokogiri::HTML('<div></div', nil, nil,  Nokogiri::XML::ParseOptions::STRICT)  this doesn't raise anything in contrast to the xml method .